# Maven Jar Build is Adding images/ant_logo_large.gif - Want to NOT Include It

Tags: maven, maven-3

My Maven jar build is including images/ant_logo_large.gif in the jar. Why is it doing that and how can I prevent it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was being included because one of the Maven dependencies was including Ant as a dependency, and the Ant jar has the logo. And when I was building the jar with the Maven shade plugin, it included the logo.